# How to open a word file with interop.word

Tags: c#

When I open a `.docx` file through `interop.word`, I can edit it by another editor tool.

After editing it, the Interop.word find the file has been modified and will attempt to update the content edited.

My code is below:

```
Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Word.Document doc = null;
            object unknow = Type.Missing;
            app.Visible = true;
            string str = @"E:\1.doc";
            object file = str;
            doc = app.Documents.Open(ref file,
                ref unknow, ref unknow, ref unknow, ref unknow,
                ref unknow, ref unknow, ref unknow, ref unknow,
                ref unknow, ref unknow, ref unknow, ref unknow,
                ref unknow, ref unknow, ref unknow);
```

The error I get is telling me that the file is opened.

Comment: Its always best to show the work and code that you have tried when asking a question. Also - the question is a little difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need all the parameters if you not using them - this should do the same job:

Create new instance of the application:

```
Word.WordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

or

```
Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

Add a new document:

```
Word.WordApplication.Documents.Add()
```

Then open it:

```
Word.WordApplication.Documents.Open(documentPath)
```

If you need to open the document in ReadOnly set to true then use this:

```
Word.WordApplication.Documents.Open(documentPath, ReadOnly:=True)
```

Comment: Yes,but i can not still use a third component to open the file because the file is opened by the Word.Application.

Comment: Why are you trying to open the same document using multiple applications? You could check if Word has the document open and close it first?

Comment: Because I want multiple applications to edit the same file at the same time. Otherwise when one application need to edit it ,another application must close ,it is discommodious.

Comment: The solution you provided is useful , thank you very much.

Comment: How to check if Word has the document open ? I can not find the api.

Comment: @cn-deng glad to hear it helped, don't forget to accept the answer.. :)  I'm not in front of my pc at the moment but you can do something like foreach document in word.wordapplicaton.documents, then check for the doc name or id.