# Open .doc or .xls by SDK or Interop from byte[]

Tags: c#, sdk, interop

I have a Word document as byte []. Me need open this document. How can I do it?
If it will be not so hard for you please give two examples.
How to open doc by OpenXML SDK.
How to open doc by Interop.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = @"C:\tmp\TestDoc.docx";
 
            byte[] DocData;
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                DocData = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(DocData, 0, DocData.Length);
            }
 
            //Delay
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));
            Console.WriteLine("Ready!");
            Console.ReadKey();
 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this answer on how to open document via Interop, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36996351/7342859.

Comment: I have byte[]. How can I do file from byte[]?

Comment: use what you've got in `filename`, you don't need to read the file beforehand when you're using Interop.

Comment: I have got this file from DB

Comment: Chips, I believe you'll have to write it to disk first as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43762620/7342859.